# FileIOException: File already exists error on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

i get thumbnail image using fileconnection.

I get image using thread constructor. I pass the url and get image.

If the two image url are same , i got exception "FileIOException: File already exists "

My code is here.,

```
FileConnection fConn = null;
try 
{
        String fileString = MD5.encodeStringMD5(url);
        fConn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(fileTempPath+fileString+".png");
        if(!fConn.exists())
        {
                fConn.create();
                GetImageFromURL(url,fConn,id);
        }
        else
        {
                 GetImageFromFolder(fConn, id);
        }
        fConn.close();
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
       System.out.println("------"+e);
}
```

If the urls are differ. No problem occur. But if two or three url r same , Only one image only stored and load on screen. others same url not displaying.

After stored on device memory, its loadding all image.

The Exception throws in this line - "fConn.create();"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before creating a new file, try to open a file with the same name/path. If it already exists remove it.

Comment: Hi. I check the file connection   if(!fConn.exists())
        {}

Comment: Use System.out.println and/or EventLogger class to log the full path you are using to open/check file presence. And check the file presence manually, using this information. Does the file exists when you invoke !fConn.exist() or not.

Comment: I create a thread class and create five object for the thread class. I pass the  url . When one fconn is create and ready to write on it, at the same time the second object call in thread , if the fcon is same the error occur.

Comment: I think there's a typical synchronization problem. Between fConn.exists() and fConn.create() there is another thread that creates file with the same path/filename.

Comment: Yes. i think same. Pls hlp how to synchronized this.

Comment: Here is the link to tutorial: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_1.shtml

Comment: use this synchronized (UiApplication.getUiApplication().getAppEventLock()) 
{
 sampleThread thread=new sampleThread();
 thread.start();
}

Comment: @Rafael Osipov r you there,i have some doubts please come this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3177/life-for-blackberry plese please please sir

Answer (score 1):

If file already exits then do like this:

```
if(!fConn.exists())
    {
            fConn.create();
            GetImageFromURL(url,fConn,id);
    }
    else
    {
             fConn.truncate();//it removes the data in that file;
             GetImageFromFolder(url,fConn, id);
    }
```